# insert json array inside mongoDB document

Tags: json, ruby, mongodb

i make a ruby script which generate array json file.
i want to store them inside a single mongoDb document, how can i do this?

ruby generate json data like:

```
{
{key1 : value1}
{key2 : value2}
{key3 : value3}
}
```

and in mongo i want a document structure like this:

```
ID(document) : {
{key1 : value1},
{key2 : value2},
{key3 : value3},
}
```

how can i do this throught ruby?
i tried with: `insert_many(:id ID(document), :json_coll my_json_collection)` or `insert_one(my_json_collection)`, but mongo decide to save 1 json file inside 1 document and create thousands of documents, how can i save all json array inside a single document?
thank you.

Comment: `insert_many(:id ID(document), :json_coll my_json_collection)` isn't valid Ruby syntax. Can you show the actual Ruby code you are using to create the document?

Comment: i cant show sensible content, but you imagine that this script create a file .log, which inside there are json array. and i want to insert the content for each file in each document,  1 file.log = 1 document

Comment: how can i do this?

Comment: How does your Ruby script communicate with MongoDB? Are you using the `mongo` gem or an object mapper like Mongoid?

Comment: i use mongo gem, with require "mongo", and for example: client = Mongo::Client.new(...) inside the code. I dont use mongoId

Comment: You already posted this question yesterday. I'm going to close this one as a duplicate. Please update the other question accordingly.